# SDL_rect.h giving SDL_bool warning

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I've been trying to run a program using SDL2 but each time I try to run it SDL_Rect gives me a warning:

```
The enum type 'SDL_bool' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum'(Enum.3)
```

I have the newest version of SDL2 2.0.14 for Visual Studio C++ everything seems to be working except for that one header.

Here is the code:

```
#ifndef SDL_rect_h_
#define SDL_rect_h_

#include "SDL_stdinc.h"
#include "SDL_error.h"
#include "SDL_pixels.h"
#include "SDL_rwops.h"

#include "begin_code.h"
/* Set up for C function definitions, even when using C++ */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/**
 *  \brief  The structure that defines a point (integer)
 *
 *  \sa SDL_EnclosePoints
 *  \sa SDL_PointInRect
 */
typedef struct SDL_Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
} SDL_Point;

/**
 *  \brief  The structure that defines a point (floating point)
 *
 *  \sa SDL_EnclosePoints
 *  \sa SDL_PointInRect
 */
typedef struct SDL_FPoint
{
    float x;
    float y;
} SDL_FPoint;


/**
 *  \brief A rectangle, with the origin at the upper left (integer).
 *
 *  \sa SDL_RectEmpty
 *  \sa SDL_RectEquals
 *  \sa SDL_HasIntersection
 *  \sa SDL_IntersectRect
 *  \sa SDL_UnionRect
 *  \sa SDL_EnclosePoints
 */
typedef struct SDL_Rect
{
    int x, y;
    int w, h;
} SDL_Rect;


/**
 *  \brief A rectangle, with the origin at the upper left (floating point).
 */
typedef struct SDL_FRect
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float w;
    float h;
} SDL_FRect;


/**
 *  \brief Returns true if point resides inside a rectangle.
 */
SDL_FORCE_INLINE SDL_bool SDL_PointInRect(const SDL_Point *p, const SDL_Rect *r)
{
    return ( (p->x >= r->x) && (p->x < (r->x + r->w)) &&
             (p->y >= r->y) && (p->y < (r->y + r->h)) ) ? SDL_TRUE : SDL_FALSE;
}

/**
 *  \brief Returns true if the rectangle has no area.
 */
SDL_FORCE_INLINE SDL_bool SDL_RectEmpty(const SDL_Rect *r)
{
    return ((!r) || (r->w <= 0) || (r->h <= 0)) ? SDL_TRUE : SDL_FALSE;
}

/**
 *  \brief Returns true if the two rectangles are equal.
 */
SDL_FORCE_INLINE SDL_bool SDL_RectEquals(const SDL_Rect *a, const SDL_Rect *b)
{
    return (a && b && (a->x == b->x) && (a->y == b->y) &&
            (a->w == b->w) && (a->h == b->h)) ? SDL_TRUE : SDL_FALSE;
}

/**
 *  \brief Determine whether two rectangles intersect.
 *
 *  \return SDL_TRUE if there is an intersection, SDL_FALSE otherwise.
 */
extern DECLSPEC SDL_bool SDLCALL SDL_HasIntersection(const SDL_Rect * A,
                                                     const SDL_Rect * B);

/**
 *  \brief Calculate the intersection of two rectangles.
 *
 *  \return SDL_TRUE if there is an intersection, SDL_FALSE otherwise.
 */
extern DECLSPEC SDL_bool SDLCALL SDL_IntersectRect(const SDL_Rect * A,
                                                   const SDL_Rect * B,
                                                   SDL_Rect * result);

/**
 *  \brief Calculate the union of two rectangles.
 */
extern DECLSPEC void SDLCALL SDL_UnionRect(const SDL_Rect * A,
                                           const SDL_Rect * B,
                                           SDL_Rect * result);

/**
 *  \brief Calculate a minimal rectangle enclosing a set of points
 *
 *  \return SDL_TRUE if any points were within the clipping rect
 */
extern DECLSPEC SDL_bool SDLCALL SDL_EnclosePoints(const SDL_Point * points,
                                                   int count,
                                                   const SDL_Rect * clip,
                                                   SDL_Rect * result);

/**
 *  \brief Calculate the intersection of a rectangle and line segment.
 *
 *  \return SDL_TRUE if there is an intersection, SDL_FALSE otherwise.
 */
extern DECLSPEC SDL_bool SDLCALL SDL_IntersectRectAndLine(const SDL_Rect *
                                                          rect, int *X1,
                                                          int *Y1, int *X2,
                                                          int *Y2);

/* Ends C function definitions when using C++ */
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#include "close_code.h"

#endif /* SDL_rect_h_ */
```

Comment: It's a harmless warning. [Disable it](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/no-option-to-suppress-c-code-analysis-warning-c268/724840) (read the 'fixed in' comments at the bottom of the post).

Comment: There are two options: 1) Rewrite SDL to use `bool` or `enum class` or 2) ignore the suggestion and [disable the warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=msvc-160). I suggest the latter because the former's going to be quite an undertaking.

Comment: Thanks I was actually just reading that. I'm a bit dumb though lol.. Where would I put this part of the code? Is it just one location at the top or in each line that has SDL_rect?

Comment: Disabling actually makes it worse as now I get warnings from the program I wanted to make. Such as "Using uninitialized x" and still getting the bool error for some weird reason..

Comment: Sounds like you made a mistake.  The link I gave shows how to disable the warning - if you have a new enough version of MSVC - and you do it at the point where you #include the SDL header files.

Comment: Figured it out thanks a lot, I was disabling it wrong lol. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix SDL_RECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67796818/how-do-i-fix-sdl-rect)

Comment: Can't be a dupe -- that question is Closed.

Comment: Yeah it was one of my first posts unfortunately it was too vague. So I decided to repost but and good thing because now I got through my problem!